# Memory blows up in Docker when loading ML models

Tags: docker, machine-learning, xgboost, mlops

Uploading 4 XGboost models takes about 12 GB when I load it locally. When I try to load the same (ML) models, the 26 GB I gave it runs out. Any idea why? or how can I fix this?